# Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, desktop-application

We are builing a windows desktop application (not web based) and trying to come up with the best way to implement Repository and UnitOfWork Pattern.

In a typical Asp.Net Mvc application your repositories are injected with data context, services are injected with repositories and finally controllers are injected with services and all is well if you don't hit any exception, you will commit the changes.

In windows forms/wpf applications it is not advisable to use single datacontext ( [Oren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) has a post on this on MSDN) so we have decided to create data context at the presenter. We are using Linq2SQl and we have two different databases to work with based on the view.

Currently I have the following implementation

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        ...
     }

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly Table<T> _table;

        public Repository(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            _table = dataContext.GetTable<T>();
        }
   }

public Class TodoService :ITodoService
{
       IRepository<Todo> _todoRepository;
       public TodoService(DataContext dataContext)
       {
           _todoRepository = new Repository<Todo>(dataContext)
       }
       ...
}
```

}

// Presenter for the UI

```
public class TodoPresenter
{
    public void Save()
    {
       Using (DataContext dataContext = DataContextFactory.GetNewContextForDatabase1())
       {
           ITodoService service = new TodoService(dataContext);
            ...
           service.Save(..);
           dataContext.SubmitChanges();           
       }
    }
```

}

I would like decouple the presenter from service and would like to inject TodoService when ITodoService is requested, but I cannot inject data context for two reasons, as I have to decide based on the database or can't even maintain a data context at the application level even if we have only one database being a windows application (many views are open at a time as tabs in the app) and with no data context I cannot create Repository classes and can't inject services.

Any idea on how to achieve decoupling in this situation

Comment: Take a look at this: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 > I cannot inject data context
```

but maybe you can inject a factory method that creates the context and the service

```
public class TodoPresenter
{
    private Func<DataContext> dataContextFactory;
    private Func<DataContext, ITodoService> serviceFactory;

    // created with new TodoPresenter(DataContextFactory.GetNewContextForDatabase1(), 
    //                   dc => new TodoService(dc, 
    //                              new ToDoRepository(dc => new ToDoRepository(dc))));
    public TodoPresenter(Func<DataContext> dataContextFactory, 
                         Func<DataContext, ITodoService> serviceFactory)
    {
        this.dataContextFactory = dataContextFactory;
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        using (DataContext dataContext = this.dataContextFactory())
        {
            ITodoService service = serviceFactory(dataContext);
            // ...
            //service.Save(..);
            //dataContext.SubmitChanges();           
        }

    }
}
```

**Update**

The Service needs a factory to get the repository as well

```
public TodoService(DataContext dataContext, 
         Func<DataContext, IRepository<Todo> todoRepository){...}
```

An integrationtest with Service and presenter looks like this

```
  var toDoRepository = new Mock<..>(..);
  var datacontext= new Mock<..>(..);
  var presenter = new TodoPresenter(dc => datacontext, 
                  dc => new TodoService(dc, dc2 => toDoRepository ));
```

An unitest for presenter starts like this

```
  var TodoService= new Mock<..>(..);
  var datacontext= new Mock<..>(..);
  var presenter = new TodoPresenter(dc => datacontext, 
                  dc => TodoService);
```

Comment: This _is_ dependency injection. My only critique, would be that passing in the Func<> arguments makes test setup a little more involved. I'd use interfaces and adapters to make sure that the arguments were pure interfaces and I could mock them for test.

Comment: k3b: +1, how do I extend it to Service as well, TodoService is creating TodoRepository directly, do I have to use factory there as well and pass the implementation from service on which repository to use? And how do I mock it in that case the whole service and repository classes

Comment: why not TodoPresenter(mockDC.Object, mockTodoService.Object) so that you don't end up testing the TodoService class in your unit tests. Coupling to TodoService in your tests just makes them more fragile when code changes, and obscures the intent of the test (during setup at least).

Comment: @Ritch Melton : I agree. Just wanted to show the syntax. Updated my article. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the datacontext inside a UnitOfWork. And create a unitofwork either per call/session.

Comment: I am not using external service like wcf to wrap the data context in per call or session, it's desktop application and in some cases (which I don't want to get into) we directly write to database with out service

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to create the datacontext in the todoservice?

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    void Save(T item);
    void SubmitChanges();
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public void Save(T item)
    {
    }

    public void SubmitChanges()
    {
    }
}
```

// TodoService will have its local datacontext

```
public class TodoService :IDisposable
{
   DataContext dataContext;
   IRepository<Todo> _todoRepository;
   public TodoService()
   {
       dataContext = DataContextFactory.GetNewContextForDatabase1();
       _todoRepository = new Repository<Todo>(dataContext);
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       dataContext.Dispose();
   }

   void Save(Todo item)
   {
       _todoRepository.Save(item);
   }

   void SubmitChanges()
   {
       _todoRepository.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

// presenter

```
class TodoPresenter
{
    public void Save()
    {
       using (TodoService service = new TodoService())
       {
           Todo item = null;
           // ...
           service.Save(item);
           service.SubmitChanges();           
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. As the data context is created inside the service, if my presenter happens to use multiple services I cannot share the data context and commit/rollback changes across services. 2. Can't use TodoService with another database as it is instantiating the data context.