# Converting from closed generics to open generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am looking for a way to convert the following closed generics statement to open generic statement, i.e. I don't want repeat the same for entities like User, Employer, etc.

Closed type using User:

```
UnityContainer.RegisterType<Func<IDataContextAdapter, IRepository<User>>>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => 
                    new Func<IDataContextAdapter, IRepository<User>>(
                        context => new Repository<User>(context))
        )
 );
```

I tried converting to Open generics by applying typeof(..) operation, but didn't had much success. 
  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make generic Function

```
public void Bla<T>() where T:class
{
UnityContainer.RegisterType<Func<IDataContextAdapter, IRepository<T>>>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => 
                    new Func<IDataContextAdapter, IRepository<T>>(
                        context => new Repository<T>(context))
        )
 );
}
```

Comment: It works, but still need to call the function multiple times for all the repository entities in my application. Looking for something generic using typeof operator.